# new process tcp dump in c#

Tags: c#, process, createprocess, tcpdump

I am trying to create a process to run tcpdump in my program..

here is the code

```
            Process tcpdump = new Process();
            tcpdump.StartInfo.FileName= @"/usr/local/bin/tcpdump";
            tcpdump.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            tcpdump.StartInfo.Arguments = " -i en1 -c 10 -nn tcp and src host " + ip + " and port " + ports[i];
            tcpdump.Start();
            tcpdump.WaitForExit();
```

However I got error and the process doesn't start correctly 
and this is the error message I get

```
open: invalid option -- i
Usage: open [-e] [-t] [-f] [-W] [-R] [-n] [-g] [-h] [-b <bundle identifier>] [-a <application>] [filenames] [--args arguments]
Help: Open opens files from a shell.
      By default, opens each file using the default application for that file.  
      If the file is in the form of a URL, the file will be opened as a URL.
Options: 
      -a                Opens with the specified application.
      -b                Opens with the specified application bundle identifier.
      -e                Opens with TextEdit.
      -t                Opens with default text editor.
      -f                Reads input from standard input and opens with TextEdit.
      -F  --fresh       Launches the app fresh, that is, without restoring windows. Saved persistent state is lost, excluding Untitled documents.
      -R, --reveal      Selects in the Finder instead of opening.
      -W, --wait-apps   Blocks until the used applications are closed (even if they were already running).
          --args        All remaining arguments are passed in argv to the application's main() function instead of opened.
      -n, --new         Open a new instance of the application even if one is already running.
      -j, --hide        Launches the app hidden.
      -g, --background  Does not bring the application to the foreground.
      -h, --header      Searches header file locations for headers matching the given filenames, and opens them.
```

Comment: Ok, my bad, I kicked out my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the way arguments are passed to the open command.

See the solution to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255624/how-to-use-process-start-or-equivalent-with-mono-on-a-mac-and-pass-in-argument) in SO.

Comment: Well I tried  it but I got another error


System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception has been thrown

ApplicationName='/usr/local/bin/tcpdump', CommandLine=' -i en1 -c 10 -nn tcp and src host 192.168.1.4 and port 80', CurrentDirectory=''

Comment: Are you able to run tcddump on the command line with the same arguments ? I suggest, you try this with another simple command  to ensure that the Process.Start(..) works correctly.

Comment: OOPPS tcpdump is not in that folder .. that's why it wasn't working.. my bad :S ... everything is great now :)

Comment: I am sorry but when now everything is working but when I add this part 

+  " > tcpdump.txt";   to redirect the output to a file .. I got tcp syntax error .. though when I use the exact same command in the shell window I got no error ... any solution ?? I think the problem with the char > ..... any help ?

Comment: Well, I am sure there must be a way around the > char... Another way is to use, 
      tcpDump.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
       //After you start the Process ...
 
      string tcptxt = tcpDump.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
      StreamWriter lFile = new StreamWriter("tcpdumpOutput.txt" );
      lFile.Write(tcptxt.ToString());
      lFile.Close();

      tcpDump.WaitForExit();

Comment: I even tried using **| tee file.txt** or **| grep file.txt** 


but I got tcp syntax error in both :S