# Send Terminal command in OS X with C#?

Tags: c#, macos, process, terminal

How can i send a command like this:

```
$ java -jar <location> <args>
```

Through the **Terminal.app** with C# on OSX?

I see lots of ways to do it on PC/windows but very little info on doing this in OS X...

Comment: C#? On OSX? Through Terminal.app? You can't do it on PC because PC doesn't have Terminal.app, so please explain exactly what you want to do: execute the command (in which case it has nothing to do with Terminal.app), or send *keystrokes* to Terminal.app, or something else? Also, why C#? Using C# on Mac is like making a wood oven in tundra: sure, you can do it (with Mono, in which case it should be in your tags), but probably not the best of ideas.

Comment: I'm using Xamarin (http://xamarin.com/studio) to compile the application. It's actually quite convenient, as i can export to both .exe and .app (for mac) with ease, however running terminal commands  is apparently a challenge

Comment: what i want to do is to run a jar with arguments.

Comment: Then again `xamarin` and `mono` should have been tags, to attract users who know about those technologies. `terminal`, on the other hand, is not - you are trying to run a process, not interact with terminal in any way. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255624/how-to-use-process-start-or-equivalent-with-mono-on-a-mac-and-pass-in-argument) helps? Also, be sure to specify the full `/path/to/java` instead of `java`.