# Trouble with parameters passing

Tags: c#, .net, macos, xamarin

I'm using C# and Xamarin on OsX.
I have two applications. One should start second with specific parameters:

**App1:**

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processInfo.FileName = path;
processInfo.Arguments = "fs,5";

using (var process = Process.Start(processInfo))
    process.WaitForExit();
```

However, when I'm trying to echo this arguments on my second application I get empty `args`:
**App2:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   foreach(var a in args)
      MessageBox.Show(a);   // instead of MessageBox, I also tried to write to text file. Same results.
}
```

On Windows this code works perfectly. What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Process.Start() or equivalent with Mono on a Mac and pass in arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255624/how-to-use-process-start-or-equivalent-with-mono-on-a-mac-and-pass-in-argument) Set `UseShellExecute = false`