# Running command line arguments in NUnit Mono

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, mono, nunit

Im using Xamarin 6.0.1, mono 4.4.1 and NUnit 3.4.1 on OSX to run a class library class that runs a command line argument

"which ios-deploy". Directly on the terminal this returns: "/usr/local/bin/ios-deploy"

How ever, in my application, the command returns "/usr/bin/which"

Any ideas as to how I can get the application to return what the terminal returns?

See my code below, thanks for your thoughts.

```
public class ProcesRunner
{

    public string getProcess()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo("/usr/bin/which", "which ios-deploy");
        p.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process pg = new Process();
        pg.StartInfo = p;
        pg.Start();
        string strOutput = pg.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string strError = pg.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(strError);
        pg.WaitForExit();
        return strOutput;
    }
}
```

Unit Test

```
[TestFixture()]
   public class Test
   {
    [Test()]
    public void TestCase()
    {
        ProcesRunner pr = new ProcesRunner();
        string outvar = pr.getProcess();
        Console.WriteLine(outvar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: Just realized from your comments this due to you running the tests within Xamarin Studio/MonoDevelop.

When starting a `Process` within an application that itself has not been given a shell environment, i.e. you clicked on an icon to launch it, vs launching it from the cli, you need to tell your process to run as a login shell (`man bash` for details) in order to run your bash profile and pick up your path settings, etc...

```
-l     Make  bash  act  as if it had been invoked as a login shell
```

Replace:

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo("/usr/bin/which", "which ios-deploy");
```

With:

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo("/bin/bash", "-l -c 'which ios-deploy'");
```

Output:

```
nunit-console -nologo bin/Debug/WhichTest.dll
.
/usr/local/bin/ios-deploy


Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Not run: 0, Time: 0.049 seconds
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, in debug mode, strOutput is empty. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @mogoli Strange, your code with my change works for me.... does `/bin/bash -c 'which ios-deploy'` on the cmd-line not return the full path of iOS-deploy?

Comment: Strange indeed, may I ask what version of Xamarin, Nunit and Mono you're using please? The command does work on the terminal directly.

Comment: Nunit 3.4.1 and 2.4.8 console runners, Mono 4.4.0, XS Version 6.1 (build 4963).

Comment: set UseShellExecute to false
reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255624/how-to-use-process-start-or-equivalent-with-mono-on-a-mac-and-pass-in-argument

Comment: @M.Hassan ? He is already using `UseShellExecute = false` (you can not redirect the i/o when it is true as it is doing an exec, as the linked SO says)

Comment: Doing some further research I do "which xcrun" in the code as an example and it works. perhaps the hyphen in ios-deploy is the issue

Comment: So the weird thing is that it works when I run the nunit test on the terminal as SushiHangover suggested, it works. But it doesnt work When I run within the Xamarin ide. I suppose this is progress, but why doe sit fail in the ide?

Comment: @mogoli Just realized you are running this test within the IDE test pad based upon your comment, I updated my answer for you.

Comment: ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo("/bin/bash", "-l -c 'which ios-deploy'");

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo("/usr/bin/which", "which ios-deploy");
```

with

```
ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo("/usr/bin/which", "ios-deploy");
```

You are passing `which` to `which` which is why your are seeing the path to `which` :)

**Edit**

If removing `which` from the arguments results in an empty string, then it is likely because `ios-deploy` is on your user path. You may need to set `p.LoadUserProfile = true` and you may need to upgrade to NUnit 3.4.1 and use the command line option `--loaduserprofile`. Along with Charlie's suggestions, it should work.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.loaduserprofile(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ProcessStartInfo p = new ProcessStartInfo("/usr/bin/which", "ios-deploy"); returns an empty string. It doesn't print the path of ios-deploy unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I have added info about using `LoadUserProfile`.

Comment: The issue seems to be with running the test in the xamarin ide. It works when I run the test from the Terminal. Weird

Answer (score 0):

You are capturing the output before the process completes. You need to move those lines after the WaitForExit.

Comment: pg.Start();

   pg.WaitForExit();

   string strOutput = pg.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
   string strError = pg.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion