# Process.Run() with Args in Mono (Linux), not starting the process

Tags: c#, unix, process, mono, arguments

I need to start updater application by passing URL of the patch file. Basic Process.Run works fine, however when I pass argument nothing happens. (This is Linux Mint and Mono)

I have already checked SO, net, etc. and tried solutions such as setting UseShellExecute to false or using ProcessStartInfo.

What am I doing wrong ? 
Updater is located in the same folder where the main exe is. 
Mono console shows no errors.

Works : (works for everyone so no surprise there)

```
Process.Start (Application.StartupPath + @"/Updater.exe");
```

Doesn't work (Nothing happens, also expected ?) :

```
Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + @"/Updater.exe", "URLToFile");
```

From other solutions I have tried :

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(Application.StartupPath + @"/Updater.exe", @"URLToFile.zip") { UseShellExecute = false });
```

I also tried many solutions proposed here :
[How to use Process.Start() or equivalent with Mono on a Mac and pass in arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255624/how-to-use-process-start-or-equivalent-with-mono-on-a-mac-and-pass-in-argument)
And I checked some other blogs and google results. No solution ever worked for me sadly.

More info that might not be as important but could help :

- Code works in Windows
- I run Mono code separated from Windows code by checking platform
- Application checks for updates then starts updater and closes itself
- Updater is located in the same folder in which the main exe is
- Updater is separated project
- This is an portable application

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to prefix "mono " since you want in fact to run mono with your .exe as an argument. Also I determine the application path in another way:

`string sAppPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);`

`Process.Start("mono " + sAppPath + @"/Updater.exe");`

Comment: I'm getting "No such file or directory" in the console using the provided example. I just noticed that the path is wrong, there is "mono" added : 
gvfs-open: mono/home/hrcak/Desktop/File/Updater.exe: error opening location: Error when getting information for file '/home/hrcak/mono/home/hrcak/Desktop/File/Updater.exe': No such file or directory

I tried using process info to start "mono" and "open". Results in same error.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I did not test my code. Now I did a small project and tested it - just a form with a label and a button. Working fine. I'm getting the right path and the HelloWorld App gets started and processes the CmdLineArg. Here the core content comes:

`private void DoIt()
{
    string sAppPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    psi.FileName = "mono";
    psi.Arguments = sAppPath + @"/HelloWorld.exe CmdLineArg";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
}`